# Secure Spring Apache CXF services with Spring Security Oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, cxf, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

I have a running Spring based Apache CXF web service. I want to use Spring Security Oauth2 to secure the existing service. I have done this for SpringREST service but i am not able to find any help for securing CXF with Spring security Oauth2. Can some one please help me.

Comment: how are you securing your rest services? using cookie or http header? What if you add header token to your cxf payload?